Is it posible in flet to place a scroll above the row?
I have made a table and I have a column and a row, with both scrolls. They are on the right and bottom. And I want it to be top and right.
correlationMatrix = ft.Column([
    ft.Row([
        ft.DataTable(
            columns= tableColumns(),
            rows=tableRows(),
            heading_row_height=40,
            column_spacing = 10
        ),
    ],scroll=ft.ScrollMode.AUTO)
],scroll=ft.ScrollMode.AUTO)



maybe you will have to check source code for Row. OR maybe you could add scroller as another widget in row/column using ScrollableControl
